# setInterval Javascript MVC2

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use setInterval to calculate time left, here is my script:

```
 var intervalID;
        function StartTimer() {
            var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
                var settimmer = 100; //  $('#timeleft').val();
                var seconds = 0;
                seconds++;
                if (seconds >= 60) {
                    settimmer--;
                    seconds = 0;
                    $('#timeleft').val(settimmer);
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
        function StopTimer() {
            clearInterval(intervalID);
        }

<input type="text" size="8" id="timeleft" name="timeleft" value="100" />
    <button onclick="StartTimer();">
        start</button>
    <button onclick="StopTimer();">
        Stop</button>
```

I does not work, however when I use the following script, it works but don't know how to stop it:

```
  var settimmer = 100;
   var seconds = 0;
    $(function () {

            window.setInterval(function () {
                seconds++;
                if (seconds >= 60) {
                    settimmer--;
                    seconds = 0;
                    $('#timeleft').val(settimmer);
                }

            }, 1000);

    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-declaring `intervalID` in the `StartTimer()` function, remove the `var`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the scope of variable. You re-declaring intervalID in the function StartTimer, and it will cover the global variable 'intervalID' and only be used in this function. In fact, the variable 'intervalID' outside is not valued.
So when you use clearInterval(intervalID), it certainly does not work.